# pandas dataframe and how to find an element using row and column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

is there a way to find the element in a pandas data frame by using the row and column values.For example, if we have a list, L = [0,3,2,3,2,4,30,7], we can use L[2] and get the value 2 in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.iloc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'L':[0,3,2,3,2,4,30,7], 'M':[10,23,22,73,72,14,130,17]})

    L    M
0   0   10
1   3   23
2   2   22
3   3   73
4   2   72
5   4   14
6  30  130
7   7   17

df.iloc[2]['L']
df.iloc[2:3, 0:1]
df.iat[2, 0]

2

df.iloc[6]['M']
df.iloc[6:7, 1:2]
df.iat[6, 1]

130
```

Comment: Thanks!! this works. The syntax working different than the numpy array, I see. we can't use column number instead of ['L']?

Comment: updated with additional examples; you want iat instead of iloc to be more like your ask.

Comment: thanks again. I suppose the index column is not counted as a column while getting an element. Cool